# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, properties, undefined

I am getting this error message when I want to update the user profile credentials:

Here's my code

**ProfileScreen.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
        history.push('/login')
    } else {
        if (!user.nom) {
            dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
        } else {
            setNom(user.nom)
            setEmail(user.email)
        }
    }
}, [dispatch, history, userInfo, user])
```

Comment: You can use optional chaining: `!user?.nom`

Comment: It gives me another error of "id" is undefined const getUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => { const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }) console.log(req.user) if (user) { res.json({ _id: user._id, nom: user.nom, email: user.email, isAdmin: user.isAdmin, }) } else { res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" }) } })

Comment: Is that ReactJS code or nodejs?

Comment: Nodejs. the previous one is reactjs

Comment: I think the error `"id" is undefined` in your nodejs code is not related to the original question you asked. But, to fix that you need to pass `{ user: id }` as payload when dispatching `dispatch(getUserDetails( { user: id } ))`. But as I don't see full code, this may give you other errors.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
        history.push('/login')
    } else {
        if (!user || !user.nom) {
            dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
        } else {
            setNom(user.nom)
            setEmail(user.email)
        }
    }
}, [dispatch, history, userInfo, user])
```

Comment: It gives me another error of "id" is undefined                                                              const getUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
    console.log(req.user)
    if (user) {
        res.json({
            _id: user._id,
            nom: user.nom,
            email: user.email,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        })
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" })
    }
})